# Can I use ⌘+num to switch between tabs in visual studio code for OSX

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I've been looking through the VS Code documentation but haven't seen anything that might let me use ⌘+n to jump to tab n. Is this possible in VS Code? I'm very used to using those hotkeys for chrome and sublime text.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your "keybindings.json" file:

```
{"key":"cmd+0", "command":"workbench.action.openLastEditorInGroup"},
{"key":"cmd+1", "command":"workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex1"}, 
{"key":"cmd+2", "command":"workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex2"}, 
{"key":"cmd+3", "command":"workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex3"},
{"key":"cmd+4", "command":"workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex4"}, 
{"key":"cmd+5", "command":"workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex5"}, 
{"key":"cmd+6", "command":"workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex6"},
{"key":"cmd+7", "command":"workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex7"},
{"key":"cmd+8", "command":"workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex8"}, 
{"key":"cmd+9", "command":"workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex9"}
```

To get the "keybindings.json" file, go to Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts then look for `For advanced customizations open and edit keybindings.json` near the top of the editor.